# How could I do face detect during recording video mode

Tags: java, android

I want to do some image processing work like face detection or something 
during the camera is  under recording video mode .

now I can recording video and save file and transfer it to my server.
but if I want to detect human face during recording,(I don't need any algorithm , I'll take it)
how can I do this? use what kind of library ?
I think I should use some method to get each frame of the recording video. but how ?

now, I use  "MediaRecorder" to capture the video .
SurfaceView , SurfaceHolder  : to show the preview screen

is anyone can give me some suggestions ? 
thank you very much in advance ^^

Comment: Hi! I m working on same .. will you please tell me how did you record video with face detection ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/vision/android/detect-faces-tutorial use this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a PreviewCallback when you set your Camera object. More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html).

That listener will give you a pixel buffer of the preview frame from time to time, which you can use to perform your face detect Algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

you may also find opencv.org helpful. as you have experienced, Android does not allow FaceDetection when recording is in progress. I am facing the same problem and after some searches I found opencv.org and I am working on it... it seems very promissing.